# Feed and e-mail updates are too slow

Tags: feature-request, questions, notifications

The tagged questions atom-feed lags behind about 4 minutes and i probably do not need to mention how long those filter emails take. This won't do at all for *competitive question answering*, i demand instant notifications of some description!

<sub>*(I am being serious by the way)*</sub>

---

**Edit:** As this request is faring just fabulously i will in all likelihood have to whip up yet another script or micro-app to get me the questions directly from the html-pages. But don't expect me to share that with you downers who are in denial, ha!

Comment: Oh snap, downvote bandwagon...

Comment: I just realized I am 14 minutes late to the downvote bandwagon, damn atom feeds.

Comment: @sixlettervariables: I allow you to still downvote me :)

Comment: Oooh, a bandwagon. Wait for me! (Although I can *kinda* see the point. What good is real-time notification if it is 4 minutes behind? Seriously.)

Comment: @EatmoreTwisters: Isn't that why i would want instant notifications, to not have this lag associated with the feed?

Answer (score 2):

"Competitive question answering" isn't the point.  I demand you get a life of some description!

Answer (score 1):

You are too casual H.B.

Click your favorite tag every minute if you want to hang out with the big boys.

Comment: Now that's what i would call having no life :D

Comment: Hey! Your ducks are dying in your farmville, go give them some corn or something.

Comment: I meant SO, i do not play any browser games besides it, i detest them passionately.

Comment: Gotcha now ;) I wouldn't call SO a browser game though, just the best MMORPG ever.

Comment: Browser game is the type, MMORPG is the genre.